# Log4net won't write to database using `AdoNetAppender`

Tags: log4net, adonetappender

Im using `AdoNetAppender` to write the logs to a database.
The connection is good since I see that the logger is connected to the database.
Moreover, if I change the database name in the connection, I can see the error in log4net trace, so the connection is good, but still the database table is empty.

here is the config file:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="100" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=LogsAffiliatePortal;integrated security=true;persist security info=True;" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>

  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
  </root>
  </log4net>
```

Here is how Im using the log:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
   private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      var configFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MyLog4NetConfigFile");
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configFile))
          {

             var f = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath  +Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(configFile);
                    XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(f));
         }

                log.Debug("yes");
                log.Error("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your buffersize is set to `100` so records will only be written to the database when there are that many log events. Set it to `1` for testing.

Comment: @stuartd - if you want to get rewarded, post it as an answer.

Comment: Just happy to help..

Answer (score 0):

A common issue is that you expect a log message, but log4net is buffering. Change you bufferSize to 1:

```
<bufferSize value="1" />
```

All messages will be logged directly.